# react, redux and typescript error during build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am very new to react and redux, I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#typescript-react-starter), 
at the part about `Making a container`, I am getting an error (fail to compile):

```
./src/containers/Hello.tsx
(24,61): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Hello' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{ enthusiasmLevel: number; name: string; } & { onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusia...'.
  Type 'typeof Hello' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ enthusiasmLevel: number; name: string; } & { onIncrement: () => IncrementEnt...'.
    Type 'typeof Hello' provides no match for the signature '(props: { enthusiasmLevel: number; name: string; } & { onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusiasm; onDecrement: () => DecrementEnthusiasm; } & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

since I am following the tutorial step by step at this stage I am not sure how to  fix this error.

Hello container:

```
import Hello from '../components/Hello';
import * as actions from '../actions/';
import { StoreState } from '../types/index';
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux';

export function mapStateToProps({ enthusiasmLevel, languageName }: StoreState) {
  return {
    enthusiasmLevel,
    name: languageName,
  };
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<actions.EnthusiasmAction>) {
  return {
    onIncrement: () => dispatch(actions.incrementEnthusiasm()),
    onDecrement: () => dispatch(actions.decrementEnthusiasm()),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hello);
```

Hello component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './Hello.css';

export interface Props {
  name: string;                   // required
  enthusiasmLevel?: number;       // optional (using ? after its name)
  onIncrement?: () => void;
  onDecrement?: () => void;
}

class Hello extends React.Component<Props, object> {
  render () {
    const { name, enthusiasmLevel = 1, onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props;

    if (enthusiasmLevel <= 0) {
      throw new Error('You could be a little more enthusiastic.');
    }

    return(
      <div className="hello">
        <div className="greeting">
          Hello {name + getExclamationMarks(enthusiasmLevel)}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={onDecrement}>-</button>
          <button onClick={onIncrement}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  }
}

export default Hello;

function getExclamationMarks (n: number) {
   return Array(n + 1).join('!');
 }
```

Comment: A guess but it looks like your component is expecting two props: EnthusiasmLevel & Name.
The container component looks like it is receiving an argument as a typeof query. have you checked that you are following the tutorial to the letter? It may be that you are instantiating your Hello container incorrectly with an argument or prop being passed to it as the wrong value...

Comment: @FrancisLeigh It is pretty much the same!

Comment: Any reason you're defining `Hello` as a class and not a function, [like the tutorial does?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#making-a-container) I'm not really a TypeScript expert but it seems like it's complaining about class signatures and that could be effected by your choice of component definition syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that **connect** function expects a stateless component while you provide a **stateful** component - since the second argument for React.Component is **object**.

I suggest to go with:

```
const Hello = ({
  name,
  enthusiasmLevel = 1,
  onIncrement,
  onDecrement
}: Props) => {
  if (enthusiasmLevel <= 0) {
    throw new Error('You could be a little more enthusiastic.');
  }
  return(
    <div className="hello">
      <div className="greeting">
        Hello {name + getExclamationMarks(enthusiasmLevel)}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={onDecrement}>-</button>
        <button onClick={onIncrement}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```